How to get work around the limit on PIXIJS alpha values?
I'm making an application that relies on a large amount of rectangles with transparency to generate a visualization.
However I'm running into the problem that PIXIJs runs into artifacts with alpha values lower than 1/127, where the hue is removed from the image or other artifacts happen due to running into a numerical limit for this value.
A minimal working example displaying this problem is available here: MWE
At worst my transparency values of individual rectangles should be at ~1/1000 with 1000 potentially overlapping rectangles. The main reason I'm using this many rectangles is due to a requirement of needing to filter data depending on attributes, which is much easier to implement by rendering a rectangle for every data point (Efficiency seems to still be fine, if pushing it a little).
Currently I'm using a sampling strategy to get around the problem, but this causes issues in the filtering. Is there a "proper" way to support transparency values lower than ~0.01 without relying on this sampling strategy?
